# How to add a base class to a mosby MVPActivity?

Tags: java, android, generics, mosby

I am looking for a way to add a base class to a [mosby](http://hannesdorfmann.com/mosby/getting-started/) MVPActivity.  Let me explain what i need.

Usually when using mosby we would declare an activity like this:

```
public class LoginActivity extends MVPActivity<LoginView, LoginPresenter> {
//...
}
```

but i would like to add a base class so that i can do the calls like this:

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity<LoginView, LoginPresenter> {
//...
}
```

and then BaseActivity would be like this :

```
abstract class BaseActivity<T, P> extends MvpActivity<T extends MvpView, P> {
}
```

but this is not working as the IDE at compile time has an error saying that "extends MvpView" has unexpected bounds. 
So how can i add  a base class to a mosby MVPActivity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply the generic parameters with your extended class definition and define it with the extension.

```
abstract class BaseActivity<V extends MvpView, P extends MvpPresenter<V>>
       extends MvpActivity<V, P> { }
```